# Merge dataframe from folder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge differents csv in Python. The files are in the same folder. All files have one column in common 'client_ID'. I tried this code:

```py
path= r'/folder_path/'
allfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in allfiles:
    df_file = pd.read_csv(file)
    df_file = pd.merge(df, df_file, on='partner_id')
     
df
```

Comment: `df` does not have `partner_id` column

Comment: no, df is empty

Comment: what is your error? Can you put the error?

Comment: KeyError: 'partner_id'

Comment: df does not have the column, you can try something like `df = pd.read_csv(allfiles[0])` then in the for loop `for file in allfiles[1:]:`

Comment: If I do:allfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in allfiles[1:]:
    df_file = pd.read_csv(allfiles[0])
    df_file = pd.merge(df, df_file, on='partner_id')
     
df    I have the same error --> Key Error: 'partner_id'

Comment: Try the second line in loop with `df = ...` ?   You probably want to accumulate the results in `df`, right ?   But the first loop, merging an empty df with something (with default inner join) seems also doesn't give what you expect.  Merge with outer join  ?

Comment: allfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in allfiles:
    df_file = pd.read_csv(allfiles[0])
    df = pd.merge(df, df_file, on='partner_id')
     
df    --> same mistake, KeyError 'partner_id'.  I think that the problem is that df is empty

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the first csv file first so that you don't start with an empty dataframe. I would edit your code like this:

```
path= r'/folder_path/'
allfiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

for i, file in enumerate(allfiles):
    if i < 1:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
    else:
        df_file = pd.read_csv(file)
        df = pd.merge(df, df_file, on='partner_id')
 
df
```